# Multiple Search Terms in List

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm looking to count whether `eth` or `btc` appear in `listy`

```
searchterms = ['btc', 'eth']
listy = ['Hello, my name is btc', 'hello, my name is ETH,', 'i love eth', '#eth is great', 'barbaric tsar', 'nothing']

cnt = round((sum(len(re.findall('eth', x.lower())) for x in listy)/(len(listy)))*100)
print(f'{cnt}%')
```

The solution only looks for `eth`.  How do I look for multiple search terms?

Bottom line: I have a list of search terms in `searchterms`. I'd like to see if any of those appear in `listy`.  From there, I can perform a percentage of how many of those terms appear in the list.

Comment: Why the solution is a %. Are you really looking for count here? It is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use the pipe "|" betwwen the values you want to search. In your code change `re.findall('eth', x.lower()` by `re.findall(r"(eth)|(btc)", x.lower()`

```py
listy = ['Hello, my name is btc', 'hello, my name is ETH,', 'i love eth', '#eth is great', 'barbaric tsar', 'nothing']

cnt = round((sum(len(re.findall(r"(eth)|(btc)", x.lower())) for x in listy)/(len(listy)))*100)
print(f'{cnt}%')
```

```
67%
```

Comment: Thank you!!! I've also seen similar things where it starts with f'{}] vs r'...'.  What is the difference?  Where can I read up on that? @LucasM.Uriarte

Comment: r it means the string will be treated as a raw string. The other f  f-string is very powerful you can for example have a variable ```my_number = 1``` and ```print(f"the value is {my_number}")``` will print the value is one, and you don't need to convert the integer to string. Similarly you easily print other python objects as list or dictionaries. I hope I have explain myself. If you what to check more on regex here is a link to a summary https://www.dataquest.io/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/python-regular-expressions-cheat-sheet.pdf

Comment: Spot on. What if the list is something like this ```listy = ['Hello, my name is btc', 'hello, my name is ETH,', 'i love eth', '#eth is great', 'barbaric tsar', 'nothing eth btc']```  Then cnt will be ```100```?!

Comment: I have just check it gives 100% because the last has double length. run only ```[re.findall(r"(eth)|(btc)", x.lower()) for x in listy]``` to check what finds, maybe you need to change how to count the finds. I can check later more details

Answer (score 0):

I would say instead of complicating the problem and using re, use a simple classic list comprehension.

```
listy = ['Hello, my name is btc', 'hello, my name is ETH,', 'i love eth', '#eth is great', 'barbaric tsar', 'nothing']
print(len([i for i in listy if 'btc' in i.lower() or 'eth' in i.lower()]) * 100 / len(listy))
```

It improves the readability and the simplicity of the code.

Let me know if it helps!

Comment: Thanks for a solution suggestion.  What if I wanted to apply this to other, longer lists with increasing the search terms?  The question I posted is simple, but only for example purposes.  I'm looking for a regex solution to scale on other lists in the future. @VMSM

Comment: I can edit my question, if it helps! @DanielHao

Comment: Ideally would have a list of search terms to detect, then apply it to another list and see if any of those search terms appear in said list. @DanielHao

Comment: Ok, I now have a list of search terms in ```searchterms```.  I'd like to see if any of those appear in ```listy``` @DanielHao

Comment: @getintoityuh could u give an example? like of the list you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

a bit more of code is giving a good readability. also adding additional words to search for, just needs to add them to the list `search_for`. for counting it uses a defaultdict.

```
listy = ['Hello, my name is btc', 'hello, my name is ETH,', 'i love eth', '#eth is great', 'barbaric tsar', 'nothing']
my_dict = defaultdict(int)
search_for = ['btc', 'eth']
for word in listy:
    for sub in search_for:
        if sub in word:
            my_dict[sub] += 1
print(my_dict.items())
```